# Number of Prime factors of a Number

Tags: number-theory

Find the number of prime factors of $(30)^7 \times (22)^5 \times (34)^{11}$

My Work

The prime factorisation of the above number is $2^{34} \times 3^7 \times 5^7 \times 11^5 \times 17^{11}$

Now the number of distinct prime factors of the number is 5.

But total prime factors are=$34+7+7+5+11$

Am I going correct way?

Comment: If the prime factorization is indeed as it is given, then it suggests only that the question is poorly framed. (Unless the answer is indeed $5$ but I doubt you'd be here if that's the case.) Could you please quote, word for word, the exact question? Because something is not adding up right here.

Comment: The reasonable interpretation of this question (if there is no further context) would be to count the distinct prime factors.